# Why am I getting window.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting the getElementyById is not a function?

```
window.getElementById('notes').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 188 && e.shiftKey === true) ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 190 && e.shiftKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 191 && e.shiftKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number or alphabet and stop the keypress
    if ((e.altKey) || e.keyCode == 191 || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 90) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: its not window ,it is document.getElementById

Comment: Because it isn't. It's a method of the `document` object.

Comment: Because `getELementById` is attached to the `document` object as part of the DOM API, not to the global object `window`.

Comment: Because you need an energy drink...

Comment: BOM !== DOM. `document.getElementById(...)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right object for add listeners is `document` not `windows`.

With that said try:

`document.getElementById("elementId")`

Comment: When I use document instead of window then I get this error.( Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null)  FYI - 'notes' is a textarea.

Comment: @jdog That means you are trying to access the DOM before it's loaded so the element isn't found and is thus null. Wait till the DOM is loaded `window.onload`, etc.